# removing link from anchor tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to disable all `<a>` tags of a dynamically created table on click of another link which is outside that table using jQuery. As the table is dynamically created, my click event is not able to find the `<a>` tags inside the table. What could be the solution?

I tried `$("#tableId a").removeAttr("href")` but this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Since the table is dynamically created, use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live):

```
$('#outerLink').one('click', function ()
{
    $("#myTable a").live('click', function()
    {
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tableId a").live('click',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
return false;
});
```

Comment: There is no reason you `preventDefault()` _and_ `return false;` - but this won't work anyway, since the OP said the table is dynamically created.

Answer (score 0):

Since the table is being created dynamically you must bind `live` events like this:

```
$("#tableID a").live("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  return;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just add the `disabled` attribute to the links.

```
$("#tableID").find("a").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Answer (score 0):

In jquery 1.7 and up, the Live() method has been deprecated.  Try the following:

```
$("#tableId").on({
click: function(event){ $(this).removeAttr("href"); }
},"a");
```

as long as #tableId exists at page load.  Otherwise you would need to go up a level to something that does exist:

```
$(document).on({
click: function(event){ $(this).removeAttr("href"); }
},"a");
```